# TypeError: movies is undefined using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am importing data from an API into an array using React hooks and I am getting the error TypeError: movies is undefined.

Here is my full code:

```js
import React, { useEffect , useState } from 'react';
import axios from './axios';
import "./Row.css";

function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow = false}) {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
            const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
            setMovies(request.data.results);
            return request;
        }

        fetchData();
    }, [fetchUrl]);

    console.log(movies);

    return (
        <div className="row">
        <h2>{title}</h2>

        {movies.map(movie => (
            <img src={`${base_url}${
               isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path 
            }`}
            alt={movie.name}
            />

        ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Row;
```

When I do console.log(movies); , I seem to get a few empty arrays before it shows some arrays with data. I wonder if the error is because there are no values in the first few arrays.

[Image showing arrays in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZK1T.png)

[The error itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRDZD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer:** You are trying to read from movies array when there is not any element in the movies. You might wanna conditionally render the component so it renders after you set the movies.

```
 {movies && movies.map(movie => (
        <img src={`${base_url}${
           isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path 
        }`}
        alt={movie.name}
        />

    ))}
```

something likes this.